# How to sort my categories in Magento

Tags: php, collections, magento, categories

In the admin, you have an "order" option, you can also drag&drop categories to get it in the right order, however in the layered navigation, it doesn't seems to be take in account, the order is different.

I found Mage_Category_Helper_Category::getStoreCategories() helper method which seems to load categories, but I've not found any order option.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The drag and drop function should indeed be working... I've got a dozen of Magento stores, and they all do the same...

[image]

Look for updates on your modules or system. Maybe there is something wrong or out-of-date.

Answer (score 0):

Layered navigation should always honor the order in which you see the categories in the admin (under Catalog >> Manage Categories).  I have never seen it any different, unless the core code has somehow been altered.

So, if it is not in the same order you see it in the admin, I would check to see if any modules that have been installed, or anything you might have done is screwing with it.